# How do you un- finalize a visio layout?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a visio layout and when I try to cut an item out of the layout the entire layout is deleted. I think it is because the layout has been finalized? What do I do?

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot? Press print screen, paste into an image viewer like Irfanview, save as a PNG file and insert into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ungroup shapes before you delete any of them.

Shape > Grouping > Ungroup

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. I am trying to delete one table but when I delete it the entire layout is deleted. I tried to ungroup but the same thing happens.

Comment: I wish I could but I cannot place the image on line.

Comment: Is there a such thing as "finalizing" a layout in visio so that the layout cannot be changed at all?